# Possible to access iOS Music library via filepath/filename via Phonegap?

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, itunes

Long story short: I'd like to write a music player for iOS using Phonegap that reads the audio files in based on *directory structure and filepath/filename,* rather than ID3 tags. That is, for people like me, who organize their music via directories and filenames, this audio player would completely ignore ID3 tags and use directory structure and filename instead.

I had been told that, when transferring music to an iPhone via iTunes (as normal), the audio files are actually copied to some sort of private directory/library and renamed using completely arbitrary filenames, so:

`\Music\Red Hot Chili Peppers\Californication\04 - Scar Tissue.mp3`

would become:

`\359852728949598332567788.mp3`

making what I'm hoping to do impossible.

Is my goal a pipe dream? Are ID3 tags 100% required for developing/using an audio player on iOS?